# OpenCV Clustering Bag Of Words K-Means

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, feature-extraction

Using `SIFT Detector` and `Extractor`, with `FlannBased Matcher`, and the `Dictionary` set up for the `BOWKMeansTrainer` like this:

```
TermCriteria termCrit(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 0.001);
int dictionarySize = 15; // -- Same as number of images given in
int retries = 1;
int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

BOWKMeansTrainer trainBowTrainer(dictionarySize, termCrit, retries, flags);
```

the array size of the Clustered Extracted Keypoints will come out as `[128 x 15]`.

Then when using the `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` as the `Extractor` on a different set of 15 Images, with the previously extracted array as its `Vocabulary`, the array comes out at `[15 x 15]`.

Why?

I can't find that much on how this all actually works, rather just where to put it and what values to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result should always be `[n x 15]` if you have `n` images and `k=15`.

But in the first run, you looked at the *vocabular*, not the feature representation of the first images. The `128` you are seeing there is the SIFT dimensionality; these are 15 "typical" SIFT vectors; they are not descriptions of your images.

You *need* to read up on the BoW model, and why the outcome should ways be a vector of length `k` (potentially sparse, i.e. with many 0s) for each image. I have the impression you expect this approach to produce one 128-dimensional feature vector for each image. Also, k=15 is probably too small; and the training data set is too small as well.

Comment: So if using Feature Detectors and Extractors doesn't get me the Image Descriptions, what does?

Comment: Run `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` on your original input images, too. That is the features representation of your input images.

Comment: Now you forgot to train first... seriously, have you read documentation on the BOW approach (do you know what BOW stands for), or are you just trying to figure it out by looking at the OpenCV API?

Comment: No, I just put the `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` in the wrong place, its early man...